# How to use regex to match some words if they exist (if not match others left as well)

Tags: regex

For example, 
the string is:

```
"0x0:dqwdq0x1:dqwd0x2-0x3:sdqwd"
```

How do I match the following:

```
['0x0:', '0x1:', '0x2-0x3:']
```

in regex, or better, use re module in python? In most cases the patterns will be in 0x[0-9] but the thing is sometimes there would have an extra piece: -0x[0-9] in the string. Thanks for help!

Comment: So basically you need to match `0x#:` and `0x#-0x#:`? Can there be two digits after the `x`?

Comment: Please don't forget to select my post as the answer, if it helps. Let me know if anything goes wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below to get the 0x0:, 0x0-0x0: or even more 0x0-0x0-0x0: numbers.

```
((\dx\d)-?)+:
```

And yes, python should be able to do the job. As long as the regular expression is correct to match what you want, the language you use shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
0x\d(-0x\d)?:
```

This regex will match `0x#:` and `0x#-0x#:`, where `#` is a digit. As you can see, the part between parenthesis is optional by using that `?`.